# Работа с формами, регистрация джанго

Tags: python, django

Есть готовая `html` страница, пишу систему регистрации первый раз, везде предлогается создать свой `html` шаблон. Подскажите, как правильно работать с классом и как указать его именно в эту форму? Что писать в `URLS.PY`?

Это мой `forms.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'email')

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match.')
        return cd['password2']
```

Это `url.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', basis, name='home'), # http://127.0.0.1:8000/pljnoncoin/
    path('registration/', registration),  # hhttp://127.0.0.1:8000/pljnoncoin_reg/
    path('register/', views.register_request, name='register'),#Раньше было так, возможно нужно исправить path('register/', register, name='register')

]
```

Это `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseNotFound, Http404
from .forms import NewUserForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, UserRegistrationForm


menu = [{'title': 'Регистрация'}]
def basis(request):
    return render(request, 'women/index.html',)# Основная страница
def registration(request):
    return render(request, "women/index1.html")# регистрация
def register(request):
    return HttpResponse("Регистрация")

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            # Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            # Set the chosen password
            new_user.set_password(user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            # Save the User object
            new_user.save()
            return render(request, 'account/register_done.html', {'new_user': new_user})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'user_form': user_form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, в url.py форму не нужно указывать, там указывается ф-ция, которая будет обрабатывать ваш запрос. Форма передаётся на страничку в функции регистрации:

user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
return render(request, 'account/register.html', {'user_form': user_form})

Вам остаётся в register.html вставить в нужном месте:

```
            <body>
               <table>
                  {{ user_form }}
               </table>
            </body>
```